# How to call a lambda callback with mockk

Tags: kotlin, mocking, mockk

I create a mock of a class with mockk. 
On this mock I now call a method that gets a lambda as a parameter.

This lambda serves as a callback to deliver state changes of the callback to the caller of the method.

```
class ObjectToMock() {
    fun methodToCall(someValue: String?, observer: (State) -> Unit) {
        ...
    }
}
```

How do I configure the mock to call the passed lambda?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use [`answers`](https://mockk.io/#answers):

```
val objToMock: ObjectToMock = mockk()
# here we set up the mock to always call the second arg as a function for any arguments passed
every {  objToMock.methodToCall(any(), any())} answers {
    # alternatively: omit `invoke`
    secondArg<(String) -> Unit>().invoke("anything")
}

objToMock.methodToCall("firstArgumentString"){
    # the lambda is passed as a trailing lambda thus outside the parens
    println("invoked with $it")
}
```

Within the `answers` scope you can access `firstArg`, `secondArg`, …. To get the argument in the expected type you specify it as a generic argument (here: `(String) -> Unit`). Note that I explicitly used `invoke` here to make it more readable, it may also be omitted.

Comment: NB: This works like a charm for Kotlin lambas, if you are trying to mock an interface passed with the syntax of a lamba it will result in a `ClassCastException [...] cannot be cast to kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1`. In that case you shuld do something like `secondArg<DummyInterface>().onDummyEvent("dummy-value")`.

Comment: what if i've callback at 4th argument?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe not exactly what you ask about, but you can use the funciton type for the mock:

```
val observerMock = mockk<(State) -> Unit>()
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! An additional tip would be to relax the mock, and then use verify to ensure it was called

Answer (score 3):

I had to look for a bit more example for the callback and found some example in [Kotlin Test with Mockk](https://medium.com/@marco_cattaneo/kotlin-unit-testing-with-mockk-91d52aea2852). In my case, it's a bit more specific.
I wanted to check and mock the *onFailure* and *onSuccess* case of a a custom callback implementation `MyCustomCallback` implementing the `ListenableFutureCallback`.

The code would look like that for my `ExampleProducer` class that would have a `send` function:

```kotlin
fun send(data: String) {
    val responseFuture = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, data)
    responseFuture.addCallback(MyCustomCallback())
}
```

So here who would the test go:

```kotlin
@Test
fun onFailureTest() {
    kafkaTemplate: KafkaTemplate<String, String> = mockk()
    val captureCallback = slot<ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>>()
    
    every { callback.addCallback(capture(captureCallback)) } answers {
               captureCallback.captured.onFailure(Throwable())
    }
    every { kafkaTemplate.send(any()) } returns callback
    
    val prod: ExampleProducer = ExampleProducer()
    prod.send("test")
    
    // Then you can verify behaviour or check your captureCallback.captured
    verify { kafkaTemplate.send(any()) }
    assertNotNull(captureCallback.captured)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// GIVEN
val observerMock = mockk<(State) -> Unit>(relaxed = true)

// WHEN
ObjectToMock().methodToCall("123", observerMock)

// THEN
verify(exactly = 1) { observerMock.invoke(any()) }
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?